# Wpf .Net 4.0 client profile and caching

Tags: wpf, caching, .net-client-profile

according to msdn System.runtime.caching is not available to the client profile.  currently this caching works for .net full.
where my application is going to be deployed only supports the client profile so retargeting is not a option.
is there a open source library that will implement this functionality / or would it be better to download system.runtime.caching project from http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Caching/System/Caching
and attempt to re implement the classes removing dependency's from the full framework is this even possible ?.

Comment: This is indeed an interesting question. I suggest you reword it so that it doesn't get closed as *unclear what you're asking* nor *Primarily Opinion Based* nor *Too Broad*.  The real question is *"what alternatives are there to `System.Runtime.Caching` outside the full .Net framework?* I'm interested on implementing a generic caching library in a PCL, so an answer to your question might help me as well.