# How we can have a caching in .net 4 client profile framework

Tags: c#, wpf

'In the .NET Framework 3.5 and earlier versions, ASP.NET provided an in-memory cache implementation in the System.Web.Caching namespace. In previous versions of the .NET Framework, caching was available only in the System.Web namespace and therefore required a dependency on ASP.NET classes. In the .NET Framework 4, the `System.Runtime.Caching` namespace contains APIs that are designed for both Web and non-Web applications.'

Above are clear but What about caching in .net framework 4 client profile? I tried searching about it but i could not get the answer. I tried adding System.Web or System.RunTime.caching dll's but it could not add.

Comment: [System.Runtime.Caching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your purpose? eg If this is a web app then you would need to use a different mechanism. It's also possible you'd do better using local appdata and just serialising classes as files in there. Also, .net 4.5 is now something like 8 years old and hence client profile was .net4.0. There is no client profile in .net framework nowadays and hasn't been for quite some time.

Comment: Yeah I know it's deprecated from .net 4.5. I need it in an MVVM WPF application (using Caliburn.micro) to store data in one page and use it later in some other page.

Comment: I added a suggestion involving application.current.resources to my post.

Answer (score 0):

> Above are clear but What about caching in .net framework 4 client profile?

It's not available in the Client Profile. You need to use the full framework or find another solution to your caching needs.

Answer (score 0):

Reading this thread:
[Wpf .Net 4.0 client profile and caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808107/wpf-net-4-0-client-profile-and-caching)
It appears that System.RunTime.Caching is not included in the client profile so you wouldn't be able to use that if you have no control over .net framework version on target computers.
You could store data in a local database or serialise to appdata.
This sample serialises a class to appdata in order to persist user settings across sessions.
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/WPF-Dynamic-Fonts-ad3741ca

They're over-written on exit.

```
    private void Application_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e) 
    { 
        var fileName = Path.Combine(AppData.Location, "FontDetails.xml"); 
        if (!Directory.Exists(AppData.Location)) 
        { 
            Directory.CreateDirectory(AppData.Location); 
        } 

        FontDetails fd = Application.Current.Resources["FontDetails"] as FontDetails; 
        DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(FontDetails)); 
        var xmlSettings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true, IndentChars = "\t" }; 
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileName, xmlSettings)) 
        { 
            ser.WriteObject(writer, fd); 
        } 
    }
```

If your only purpose is to stash some data away between different windows/pages then you could push it into Application.Current.Resources.  You could start with an object in a resource dictionary you merge in app.xaml. Grab that in your first page's viewmodel. Bind to or otherwise work with that. Then grab it in your second page.
Or you could just add an object programmatically to Application.Current.Resources then grab it back out later.

```
        var myClass =  new MyClass();
        // Do whatever with it.
        // Then store it
        Application.Current.Resources.Add("CachedInstance", myClass);

        // Get it back out.
        var classLaterOn = Application.Current.Resources["CachedInstance"] as MyClass;
```